# Два определения при одном существительном

Tags: морфология

Увидел такое предложение: "Главное и добавочное действия всегда совершает одно и то же лицо/предмет". Интересует существительное "действия". Разве здесь не действует то, что написано [тут](http://www.rosental-book.ru/styli_xliv.html#sect194) под цифрой 4?

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, действует. Розенталь всегда прав (ладно: *почти* всегда).

Comment: А как быть с требованием (из того же пункта) постановки сказуемого во множественное число?  Здесь такой возможности нет, и ощущается разбаланс.

Comment: Позвольте, с какой стати сказуемое при единственном подлежащем должно быть во множественном числе?

Comment: Розенталь привязывает сказуемое в таком предложении не к подлежащему, а к "случаю" употребления единственного числа к определяемым существительным: _Сказуемое **в этих случаях** ставится в форме множественного числа..._ Наше предложение подпало бы под _оба_ требования п.4 при таком изменении: _Главное и добавочное действие всегда **совершаются** одним и тем же лицом._

Comment: Alex_ander, не понял вас: какое сказуемое в каком предложении к какому случаю употребления привязывает Розенталь? «Главное и добавочное действие всегда совершаются одним и тем же лицом» — what?! Действие (ед.) — совершаются (мн.)?!

Comment: Да, множественное. Пример Розенталя (по той же ссылке из вопроса): _Правая и левая половина дома **были освещены**._

Comment: По-моему, здесь другое. «Правая и левая половина» — две части целого (дома). А «главное и добавочное действие» — две части чего? Впрочем, я всё же написал бы «правая и левая половинЫ дома».

Comment: Это два парных "термина" (ясно, что эта условность д. б. растолкована в предш.  тексте). "Частями" чего-л. они и не должны быть (у Розенталя есть "левая и правая рука"), хотя при желании могут входить в какое-нибудь составное действие. Вы и без этого согласились в ответе отнести этот случай к соотв. пункту из Розенталя.

Comment: «Вы и без этого согласились в ответе отнести этот случай к соотв. пункту из Розенталя» к соотв. пункту» — «этот случай» я согласился отнести «к соотв. пункту» в том отношении, что я тоже нахожу вполне нормальным, чтобы ОДНО существительное имело ДВА определения. В примере из вопроса — чтобы абстрактное «действие» могло, в разных ситуациях определяясь как «главное действие» и «добавочное действие», не становиться при этом в каждом отдельном случае несколькими «действиями». Но какое отношение это имеет к сказуемому фразы в вопросе?

Comment: Я считаю, что исходное предложение верно и _не_ подпадает под тот пункт. При изменении под единственное число существительного оно звучало бы неестественно, поскольку множественность в нём не выражена дополнительными грамматическими средствами (напр., мн. число глагола), в отличие от случаев, рассмотренных у Розенталя. Я привёл изменённый вариант, который _входит_ в число таких случаев.

Comment: «При изменении под единственное число существительного оно звучало бы неестественно, поскольку множественность в нём не выражена дополнительными грамматическими средствами (напр., мн. число глагола)» — что-что? При изменении под единственное число какого существительного? Почему глагол должен быть во мн. числе, если он относится к существительному в ед.?